# First record of a sequence is always fetching?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var trainingclasses = this.trainingClassRepository.GetAllclassSession().Include(x => x.Trainer).Include(x => x.TrainingRoom).Include(x => x.Session).Where(x => x.ClassId == id);
foreach (var tclass in trainingclasses)
{
    double roomcost = trainingclasses.Select(x => x.TrainingRoom.CostPerHour).FirstOrDefault();
    double trainercost = trainingclasses.Select(x => x.Trainer.Cost).FirstOrDefault();
    double duration = trainingclasses.Select(x => x.Session.Duration).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

In above code first record of a sequence is always fetching.Can anyone plz help on this.

Comment: Its not clear, What you want?

Comment: But that's exactly what you are telling it with `FirstOrDefault`. What do you expect the outcome to be?

Comment: whats your exact question???? Are you getting only first record or you want to get first record only???

Comment: somewhere, a reactor casing is hissing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use your collection in foreach, you are iterating through list, so you can get data from tclass not from trainingClasses. Only first item was fetched because you used `FirstOrDefault`

Change to this code

```
foreach (var tclass in trainingclasses)
{
    double roomcost = tclass.TrainingRoom.CostPerHour;
    double trainercost = tclass.Trainer.Cost;
    double duration = tclass.Session.Duration;
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks its working fine.Actually i forgot use tclass.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear,

Change your code as

```
double roomcost = tclass.TrainingRoom.CostPerHour;
```

instead of

```
double roomcost = trainingclasses.Select(x => x.TrainingRoom.CostPerHour).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call .ToList() to materialize your collection

```
var trainingclasses = this.trainingClassRepository.GetAllclassSession().Include(x => x.Trainer).Include(x => x.TrainingRoom).Include(x => x.Session).Where(x => x.ClassId == id).ToList();
```